# Google playstore developer console issue?

Tags: android, developer-console

Developer console of playstore is showing only active installs
Earlier i used to see **active installs/total downloads** , but now can't find total downloads,

Do i need to change some settings in developer console ?

Comment: got the answer : open dash board of selected app , click on statistics,click on configure report ,select user installs and active installs,select time period as life time

Answer (score 0):

No this update is change by google only,they removed total downloads, so do not worry about this.